# Running automate tests with appium and selenium grid only run in one device

Tags: android, python, appium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to have some mobile automated tests running with appium and selenium grid. Once i done all configuration stuff and added grid nodes, how do i run my tests parallely in both devices?

Here's my `setUp()`:

```
desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = ''
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/workspace/XXXX/apps/XXXXX.apk'))
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'XXXXXXXX'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.MainActivity'
    desired_caps['noReset'] = False
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

What it supposed to be in `deviceName` in this case?

If i leave it blank, here's what i got:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\workspace\XXXXX>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub

19:16:58.691 INFO - Launching a selenium grid server

2016-02-18 19:16:59.937:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT

2016-02-18 19:16:59.968:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:startedo.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}2016-02-18 19:16:59.995:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:StartedSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4444

19:49:48.183 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities[{app=C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\workspace\XXXXX\apps\XXXXX.apk, appPackage=XXXXXXX, appActivity=.MainActivity, noReset=true, platformVersion=5.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=}]

19:49:48.183 INFO - Available nodes: [host :http://127.0.0.1:4723, host :http://127.0.0.1:4733]

 19:49:48.183 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://127.0.0.1:4723

19:49:48.183 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {newCommandTimeout=30, browserName=Android, maxInstances=1, version=5.1,deviceName=0429058934,deviceReadyTimeout=5, platform=ANDROID}
```

I only able to run the one registered node in grid. I even tried to create a script with `two setup()`, each one to each device, but even this way, tests only ran in this same device one device.

Here is my grid console:

[image]

Comment: deviceName is required but arbitrary for Android (for iOS it determines the kind of iOS device to launch). I noticed you don't have "avd" capability set, though. Do you have a real device plugged in with usb debugging enabled?

Comment: @econoMichael Yes, i have two physical phones with usb debugging enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
    I did try to run tests using Grid with Appium server in java, same logic you can adopt for your own language. Here is the explanation:

    1. This is the same content of node.json file on two node machines:

    {
    "capabilities":
         [
           {
             "version":"4.4.2",
             "maxInstances": 3,
             "platformName":"ANDROID"
           }
         ],
    "configuration":
    {
       "cleanUpCycle":2000,
       "timeout":30000,
       "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
       "url":"http://WHERE_APPIUM_RUNNNING:4723/wd/hub",
       "host": "WHERE_APPIUM_RUNNNING_IP",
       "port": 4723,
       "maxSession": 6,
       "register": true,
       "registerCycle": 5000,
       "hubPort": 4444,
       "hubHost": "WHERE_HUB_RUNNNING_IP"
    }
    } 

    2. Downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar and started as hub on one machine like: 
    java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role hub maxInstances=2 maxSessions=2 

    3. Started ONLY appium server on node machines and registered with hub using command as: appium --nodeconfig ~/Desktop/node.json

    4. Now declare all the common capability in GridTest.java and only deviceName was passed from testNG.xml in order to avoid any hardcoding in code and keeping node.config as generic for all node machines, sample testNG.xml is like:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Automation" parallel="tests">

        <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="XYZZZZZ" />
            <classes>
                <class name="poc.grid.GridTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>

        <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="ZYXXXXX" />
            <classes>
                <class name="poc.grid.GridTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>

    </suite>

    5. And I wrote a GridTest.java class like:

    package poc.grid;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;


    public class GridTest {

        @Parameters({"deviceName"})
        @Test
        public void test (String deviceName) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
        {
            appium_driver(deviceName);
        }

        public void appium_driver(String deviceName)
        {
            try
            {
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
                capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

                if(deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("4d0025b440ca90d5")){
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/XXXXXX/chocolate.apk");
                }else{
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/XXXXXX/chocolate.apk");
                }

                capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "120");
                WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://WHERE_HUB_RUNNNING_IP:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


6. If you are using eclipse, then Right Click on testNG.xml and select Run As --> TestNg Suite.

7. Now you can see I've kept a condition only for apk file location because the node machines have different directory, if possible you should choose a similar location which exists in all node machines, else you may have to live with if - else.  Hope This Helps !!
```

Comment: Heheheh, no. I mean that i tried almost of it before asking here :/

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you are try to run your tests concurrently, right?

If so, I haven't seen anything about threads in your post, and without threads your test will run serially.

The Selenium Grid doesn't round-robin connections for the same kind of resource. It simply allocates the first available machine. I.E. if test 'A' requests a specific browser/platform/device config, and runs to completion, then if test 'B' comes along and asks for the same config, it'll get the same machine that test A got. Make sense?

If you want to parallelize your tests, I would recommend checking out [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) & the [xdist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) plugin. This will handle all the threading/multiprocess stuff for you.

Fun fact, even if you wrote everything to use unittest, you don't have to rewrite everything to use pytest; just point pytest at your existing code.

Comment: Huuum, ok. But how i say that i want to run to run in two browsers/platforms/devices? Once my test is done in the first avaliable machine, selenium should perfom my test in the next machine. But this doesnt happens.

Comment: Are your two machines identical? From the image in your post I cannot tell. If they are identical, you'll have to split your tests into two different suites. If your two machines are not identical, you'll need to two different test suites where you request different 'desired_capabilities'. *assuming you are using pytest and the xdist plugin.

Comment: You mean like a runner? It is possible to run only one test script on several phones?